# Which files should I add to gitignore when working with SpriteBuilder?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, spritebuilder

---

Hello everyone!

I'm about to start my first project using SpriteBuilder and Xcode. I want to set up git.

While I usually add the common Xcode files to gitignore (the ones in the list below) I'm not sure which SpriteBuilder specific files I should ignore.

I'm thinking I should probably ignore:

```
.ppng 
.ccbLang
```

I'm also not sure if I should keep track of **.ccb and .ccbproj** files.

Any help really is appreciated!

**Here is my typical list of Xcode files I ignore:**

```
*.pbxuser
*.mode2v3
*.mode1v3
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*~.nib
PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/*
PROJECTNAME.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/*
*.xcuserstate
*~
*.lock
*.DS_Store
*.swp
*.out
```

Comment: keep those but exclude the Resources/Published folder(s) and subfolders because these files are created via sb publish button

Answer (score -1):

A general approach would be:

- Backup all your files (`cp -r myproject{,.backup}`)
- Delete the files you suspect are useless
- Try to open your project

If you can't, you probably should version this file. Just retrieve it from the backup.

If you can, this file is likely auto-generated, so you could add it to your `.gitignore`